# Apps activities - uniquely identify user

Tags: google-api

Is there any way how to **uniquely identify** user who caused an event? I want to extract all events from [Appsactivity](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/activity/) service, which belongs to specific user.

The problem is, that `service.activities().list()` returns also activities of other users of shared file, even if this request has set userId which indicates the user to return activity for. It returns all visible activities to given user and therefore it contains activities of other users.

I tried to filter list, but it seems to be impossible - events contains simple [User](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/appsactivity/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/appsactivity/model/User.html) object which does not have `userId` or `userEmail`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to compare user's **photo url** which is avalaible in appactivity [User](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/appsactivity/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/appsactivity/model/User.html) object. Note, that this can be done only if url is not `null`, otherwise it won't uniquely identify user.